# Sin and tawaba in Ramadan

Tags: sawm, ramadan, sin, tawba

I read Quran and i pray 5 times a day but today is Ramadan and I did a bad sin by mistake I didn't feel anything when I did sin I forgot about everything but after the sin I was really sad that I did a sin I said to myself that Allah will not forgive me because it was Ramadan and it may break my fast I want to know that will Allah forgive me? will he accept my repentance?

Comment: Please use meaningful question titles and tags. Further you should know that the greater sin is thinking bad of Allah (that He won't accept your repentance) and giving a month more respect than it should have (a sin is a sin no matter when you do it, yes it might be multiplied under certain conditions and times, but not in Ramadan). You should fear Allah and have hope in His forgiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum,
If u feel guilty, regret the sin and had asked allah for forgiveness, u are the best of sinners, meaning u are probably forgiven so dont worry.